# How to make a Shortcuts menu that open with new window or tab?

Tags: files

In Drupal 7, I added the "IMCE" url(www.mydomain.com/imce) into the Shortcuts menu for user to upload file. How to make this menu to open in a new window or tab?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Shortcuts are menu items, so you might be able to use [Menu Attributes](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_attributes) to set the target to `_blank`.

Comment: My site already has Menu Attributes module installed, but this feature is not on "Shortcuts".